# One-liner to change start and end of the filename

Tags: bash, unix, mv

I need to rename all files with a prefix in directory to corresponding names with a special postfix.

For example, let's say I have a bunch of files named like:

```
first_0001.txt
second_0001.txt
first_0002.txt
second_0002.txt
...
```

What I need to do is to rename them so that their corresponding names would be:

```
0001_1.txt
0001_2.txt
0002_1.txt
0002_2.txt
...
```

I've tried doing this with

```sh
for file in `ls`; do
    mv $file ${file/first*/*_1.txt}
done
```

but this only renames all the files to have same names, which is not needed. So the pattern of change is:

1. If the filename begins with "first_", this part should be removed and a postfix "_1" should be added before the file extension. e.g. **first_0001.txt** should be changed to **0001_1.txt**
2. Similarly, If the filename begins with "second_", this part should be removed and a postfix "_2" should be added before the file extension.
   e.g. **second_0001.txt** should be changed to **0001_2.txt**

Comment: @mrbelyash: In `${file/first*/*_1.txt}`  you replace a name, say, `first_second.txt`, to the string `*_1.txt', which then undergoes filename generation and expands to all files in your directory where the name ends into `_1.txt`. I suggest that you run your script using `set -x`, to see the effect of your command, and use `mv -iv` while debugging, to avoid unpleasant surprises.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding [@Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68067869/7552), if your `rename` has the -E option:

```sh
rename -n -E 'my %map = (first => 1, second => 2)' \
          -e 's/(\D+)_(\d+)(\..*)/${2}_$map{$1}$3/' {first,second}*
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner but If your version of `bash` supports `BASH_REMATCH`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in *.txt; do
  [[ $file =~ ^(first|second)_(000[12])(\.txt)$ ]] &&
  if [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" == first ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_1${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  elif [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" == second ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_2${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  fi
done
```

---

Remove the `echo`'s if you're satisfied with the output.

Comment: If you omit the `echo` and instead add `-i`  for debugging, you should be safe as well.

Comment: @user1934428, Thank you for that wonderful comment and info.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Perl-based `rename` program (sometimes called `prename`), then you can use it to do the two mappings.  The examples show a digit string between the prefix and suffix — the regexes can easily be modified to handle more general names.

```
rename 's/first_(\d)+\.txt/$1_1.txt/' first_*.txt
rename 's/second_(\d+)\.txt/$1_2.txt/' second_*.txt
```

That is not, however, a single command. Obviously, you could put a semicolon between them and put them both on a single line; I don't know whether that counts.  Combining them is tricky, at best — and not worth the effort IMO.

Comment: Might we need `${1}_1.txt` in the replacement, so we're substituting the right variable?

Comment: Not in Perl, @glennjackman.  In shell, yes, but that's Perl code in the regexes.  I haven't tested it today, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm allergic to one-liners so here's how I'd do it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -
for pathname in ./*.*; do
  filename=${pathname##*/}
  case $filename in
  'first_'*  ) postfix=_1 ;;
  'second_'* ) postfix=_2 ;;
  # ...
  *          ) continue ;;
  esac
  path=${pathname%/*}
  newname=${filename#*_}  # temporary
  newname=${newname%.*}
  extension=${pathname##*.}
  # remove `echo' if it looks good
  echo mv -- "$pathname" \
    "$path/$newname$postfix.$extension"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
for f in first_*; do g=${f#*_}; mv $f ${g%.*}_1.txt; done
for f in second_*; do g=${f#*_}; mv $f ${g%.*}_2.txt; done
```

But if you really want a crazy oneliner, you can do:

```
for pair in first,1 second,2 ; do postfix=_${pair#*,}.txt; for file in ${pair%,*}_*.txt; do rightpart=${file#*_}; echo $file ${rightpart%.*}$postfix; done; done
```